# Sessions blocking Codeigniter Cron Job

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I'm very new to creating cron jobs. Just started dabbling yesterday.

I design a website for a local realtor and I have a field in my database for 'Status' (For Sale, Pending, Sold), 'SoldDate' (NULL if not sold), and 'Visible' (Boolean). I am trying to create a cron job that checks once a day for any sold properties that 'SoldDate' is greater than 30 days in the past and if TRUE change the 'Visible' field to 0 (False).

Right now I just have a test script that adds a value to a dummy database called 'CRON' and a timestamp.

I'm using Codeigniter to build my website. Below is my code:

**Cron Controller**

```
class Cron extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cron_m');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!$this->input->is_cli_request())
        {
            echo "This script can only be accessed via the command line" . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }

        $data = array('value' => 'test');
        $this->cron_m->save($data);
        echo 'saved!';

    }

}
```

**Frontend_Controller**

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        
     }

    public function lock()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');        
        $this->load->model('user_m');   

        // Login check
        $exception_uris = array(
            'admin/user/login',
            'admin/user/logout'
        );

        if (in_array(uri_string(), $exception_uris) == FALSE)
        {
            if ($this->user_m->loggedin() == FALSE)
            {
                $uri = $this->uri->uri_string();
                $this->session->set_tempdata('uri', $uri);

                redirect('admin/user/login');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**MY_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['errors'] = array();

    }

}
```

**Cron_m Model**

```
class Cron_m extends MY_Model {

    public $_table_name = 'CRON';
    protected $_order_by = 'id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

**MY_Model**

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    public $_table_name = '';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
    protected $_order_by = 'order';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function save($data, $id = NULL)
    {

        //INSERT
        if ($id === NULL)
        {           
            !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //UPDATE
        else
        {
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $id = $filter($id);
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
            $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
        }

        return $id;

    }

}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|uploads|podcast\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Everything works fine on my local machine, but when I run the code in the terminal on my web server (php /home4/server_name/public_html/site_name/index.php cron) It doesn't run and gives me an error about a Database Error Occurred for the session database. "ip_address cannot be null"

I'm not sure why it's trying to create session data. I haven't created a session in my Fronted_Controller.

Below is the error i get:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Set-Cookie: ci_session=e9e9c8120a392b9009cd80196ce2fa2cabda516e; expires=Fri, 27-Nov-2015 01:42:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Database Error</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
}

a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
        margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="container">
                <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
                <p>Error Number: 1048</p><p>Column 'ip_address' cannot be null</p>
                <p>INSERT INTO `CI_SESSIONS` (`id`, `ip_address`, `timestamp`, `data`) VALUES ('e9e9c8120a392b9009cd80196ce2fa2cabda516e', NULL, 1448581353, '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1448581353;')</p>
                <p>Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 220</p> 
        </div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. If you need any additional information let me know. I would love any help or suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Try cron controller extending CI_Controller.

Comment: Ok, just tried it. Same result :(

Comment: There is no much sense. Session shouldn't be called. Make one more test with new different controller to see results. First just with echo than with DB insert.

Comment: Just tested that out, I tried two things. Created a "Test" controller that extended CI_Controller, same result. Also tried a "Test" controller that didn't extend anything, same result. I'm not sure where my "session" is starting. I missing something.

Comment: Check all autoloading libraries, helpers, models etc and see if somewhere is loaded session, login or similar. But problem could be in environment since in local it is working and online is not.

Comment: You're a genius! However there is another issue. Now it `Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Edit question and add `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your installation has been configured to use database for sessions... and since you are accessing your script from the terminal, the ip address was not gotten for some reason... The way out would be to not use database for session data (thats if its not required for your project). To do this, go to `application/config/config.php` and change `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` to `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;` 
That should solve it.